# How to list transactions from account address?

Tags: transactions, accounts, addresses, internal-transactions

I have a small service where people can exchange cryptocurrencies.
Every user has its own Bitcoin, Litecoin, etc address for balance deposit.
Now I want to add Ethereum. So I thought I will create account for every user and then check for incoming transactions.
But as I understood I can't get a list of transactions from account address.
This is weird. Even in the Mist wallet I don't see where ether comes from.
Only way to get transactions is to check some 3rd party blockchain explorer.

Also as I understood the proper way will be to create smart contract, because it has necessary API. But I can't create contact for each user.

Maybe I need to create only 1 contract that will "redirect" ether to my main account, but this is not very user friendly, because the user will be asked to add some extra data to the transaction so that I could understand who is who.

Any advise will be helpful.

Comment: My advise is to up-vote [#1897](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1897) on github.

Comment: @NikhilM, done.

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions is also helpful to understand.

Comment: This thread may also be useful: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth

Comment: Sorry i cannot comment so i'll ask here. @dmxhZGp1c2hh did you find a solution? If yes please post it here.

Comment: issue  #1897  has no activity for about an year

Comment: @PavelNiedoba It has no activity because they made the issue private. There's no telling if it will ever be implemented (and from the looks of that thread, it doesn't seem likely).

Comment: I'm sure this is needed by many. I'm ready to pay part of this. Is there work for ether community somewhere ?

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question correctly you want to be able to see who has deposited Eth to your contract address. This is what event logs are for.

(1) Create a contract where there is an event every time there is a transaction. e.g something like:

```
contract someContract {   

    address public owner;

    // Set the owner of the contract to be the creator of the contract i.e. you
    function someContract() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    } 

    // This is an event 
    event DepositMade(address _from, uint value);
    event WithdrawalMade(address _to, uint value);

    //Catch all function 
    function() {
        // generate an event when someone sends you Eth
        if (msg.value > 0)
            DepositMade(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    // Only the owner of the site can withdraw Eth
    modifier admin { if (msg.sender == owner) _ }

    function withdraw(uint amount, address recipient) admin {
        if(recipient.send(amount))
            WithdrawalMade(msg.sender, msg.value);
        else throw;
    }
}
```

The important bits are defining an event type `event DepositMade(address _from, uint value)` and generating an event when something happens `DepositMade(msg.sender, msg.value);`these events are stored in the event log associated with the address of the deployed contract instance.

(2) You retrieve the events on this contract using rpc `eth_newFilter` or `web3.eth.filter` e.g something like:

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter({fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest', address: contractAddress, 'topics':['0x' + web3.sha3('DepositMade(hexstring,uint256)')]});
filter.watch(function(error, result) {
   if(!error) console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am asking about regular account, not contract.

Comment: the user doesn't need to know the difference. No data is required they just send Eth to an address and the catch all function() is fired

Comment: So if I have 1000 users I need to create 1000 contracts?

Comment: No. You deploy the above contract. They send Eth to the address of that contract instance and amounts sent and the addresses of all senders are logged.

Comment: OK. I get senders address and how do I link it with my users? All my users will send ether to 1 address and how do I know who is who?

Comment: That is up to you. Perhaps they could tell you their account address when they sign up.

Comment: Or I can ask to add extra data in transaction. Both ways are not elegant from UX point of view.

Comment: This is a nice piece of code, but why waste eth logging information already logged in the blockchain?

Comment: @JackWinters It's really not trivial to pair addresses with users and could be a potential security risk.

Comment: @AlexCoventry Any pointers on doing exactly that? Code examples/use-cases seem to be sparse.

Comment: @EvilJordan, try https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3478/9841

Comment: This is not good for business solution. We talk real money, so it must be foolproof. Clients making deposits from exchanges have no idea from which address transactions are sent, multiple clients can use same address. Wallets have no options to include arbitrary data. Address per client must be generated and funds must be then forwarded to common account. There fore we need list of incoming (and outgoing - which we have)  transactions.

Comment: there's a bug in the code, this should be `WithdrawalMade(recipient, amount);` shouldn't it?

Comment: Does this cost gas?

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the etherchain.org GetAccountTransactions API that is documented at https://etherchain.org/documentation/api/ .

Eg: https://etherchain.org/api/account/0xbeef281b81d383336aca8b2b067a526227638087/tx/0 
will give you the transactions as displayed at
https://etherchain.org/account/0xbeef281b81d383336aca8b2b067a526227638087#txsent

Etherscan also has some documented APIs - https://etherscan.io/apis. Here's the equivalent API call for the same transaction data for the account as above.
http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xbeef281b81d383336aca8b2b067a526227638087&sort=asc

Comment: I think dmxhZGp1c2hh dos not want to use third party service

Comment: Etherchain.org is often in "limited feature mode" and unreliable. Etherscan.io has an API limit of 5 per second, with no way to increase. That's abysmal and borderline useless. One shouldn't trust 3rd parties for this information, no matter how trust-worthy they seem. Additionally, neither of these show token transfers, which seems to be an entirely different beast.

Comment: @EvilJordan I agree, even if it works fine now days, I don't want my business depend on it. I did that mistake with btc blockchain.info, which had many problems before, when btc was getting popular.

Answer (score 0):

[Ethplorer](https://ethplorer.io) provides a good [API](https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API) for many cases.

[Get address info](https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API#get-address-info)

[Get address history](https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API#get-last-address-operations)

and many others.
[image]