# Ether balance suddenly went to 0 and address not found on ether chain please help

Tags: mining

My address is `0x9ac0e6b745bbd98eec2d900d5ee8144157d7fc1e` and I had ether in it but it suddenly went down to `0` I have also never been able to find my address on ether chain.

Comment: Your address seems to exist
https://live.ether.camp/account/9ac0e6b745bbd98eec2d900d5ee8144157d7fc1e
There is no ETH on it though, what makes you think you had ETH on it ?

Comment: I ran  web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase),"ether") and it came up with 30

Comment: and I suppose eth.coinbase is `0x9ac0e6b745bbd98eec2d900d5ee8144157d7fc1e` ? wouldn't it be possible you have another account you asked for the balance ? you can use the snippet here : http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth to get all account balances quite easily

Comment: still saying 0, and saying I still only have one account

Comment: How would you have 30 in the 1st place? Someone sent you some? Did you mine some?

Comment: I mined some, I was at 35 mh/s and now for some reason im only at 11 now

Comment: what's your miner command, maybe you think you mined to this address and you dont ? what client you use to check balances, geth I suppose from what you entered, did you create your account with eth or geth ?

Comment: is used ethminer -G and i created the account using geth

Comment: sorry for the bombarding questions, just trying to understand, is there anything returned by  `eth.pendingTransactions` in geth ?

Comment: that returns null

Comment: here's a snippet from my history:

> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase),"ether")
10

> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase),"ether")
15

> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase),"ether")
15
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase),"ether")
30

> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase),"ether")
30

> ath.accounts
ReferenceError: 'ath' is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

> eth.accounts
["0x9ac0e6b745bbd98eec2d900d5ee8144157d7fc1e"]

> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase),"ether")
0

> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase),"ether")
0

Comment: Replying to euri10's first comment that the account seems to exist in https://live.ether.camp/account/9ac0e6b745bbd98eec2d900d5ee8144157d7fc1e , I checked a randomly made up account https://live.ether.camp/account/9ac0e6b745bbd98eec2d900d5ee8144111111111 and the web site still says that the account exists. live.ether.camp/account is not a reliable indicator that the account exists. Entering the same account into etherchain.org seems to be a better indicator of whether the account has been used and both the original poster's account and my made up account shows up as not found!

Comment: interesting, http://etherscan.io/address/0x9ac0e6b745bbd98eec2d900d5ee8144157d7fc1e finds one, https://www.etherchain.org/account/0x9ac0e6b745bbd98eec2d900d5ee8144157d7fc1e doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That account never had or ever has had ANY balance on it. Additionally, that account never had or ever has had ANY balance on it on the testnet.

My guess would be that your coinbase is referencing a different account.

https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x9ac0e6b745bbd98eec2d900d5ee8144157d7fc1e

https://etherscan.io/address/0x9ac0e6b745bbd98eec2d900d5ee8144157d7fc1e

Answer (score 1):

Moulie415, how long did it take your miner to find the 6 blocks? From https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator, you should currently be only finding a block every 11.2 days. The testnet and dev blockchain will mine at a much faster rate.

Comment: So will I only be able to see ether in my balance once i have mined a block?

Comment: No, if there is any ether in the account you will be able to see it without mining anything. What everyone is trying to ascertain is why it is you think that there should be a balance on your account? Where did you get that ETH from?

Answer (score -1):

April's fool is the answer, is it?