# How do I know if a submitted block became an uncle?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blocks, uncle-blocks

We need to detect that the submitted work became an uncle. How would I do this with geth api? I thought of checking the submitted block number later for any uncles that match my block's hash. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my scripts to check and print blocks, uncles and transactions. You will see the logic to retrieve the uncle details within the `getMinedBlocks()` function.

I've listed them separately for easier reading. If you intend to use it in `geth`, you would probably want to concatenate the following 5 functions into a single file for easy copy-pasting into the `geth` console.

**printTransaction(txHash)**

```
function printTransaction(txHash) {
  var tx = eth.getTransaction(txHash);
  if (tx != null) {
    console.log("  tx hash          : " + tx.hash + "\n"
      + "   nonce           : " + tx.nonce + "\n"
      + "   blockHash       : " + tx.blockHash + "\n"
      + "   blockNumber     : " + tx.blockNumber + "\n"
      + "   transactionIndex: " + tx.transactionIndex + "\n"
      + "   from            : " + tx.from + "\n" 
      + "   to              : " + tx.to + "\n"
      + "   value           : " + tx.value + "\n"
      + "   gasPrice        : " + tx.gasPrice + "\n"
      + "   gas             : " + tx.gas + "\n"
      + "   input           : " + tx.input);
  }
}
```

**printBlock(block)**

```
function printBlock(block) {
  console.log("Block number     : " + block.number + "\n"
    + " hash            : " + block.hash + "\n"
    + " parentHash      : " + block.parentHash + "\n"
    + " nonce           : " + block.nonce + "\n"
    + " sha3Uncles      : " + block.sha3Uncles + "\n"
    + " logsBloom       : " + block.logsBloom + "\n"
    + " transactionsRoot: " + block.transactionsRoot + "\n"
    + " stateRoot       : " + block.stateRoot + "\n"
    + " miner           : " + block.miner + "\n"
    + " difficulty      : " + block.difficulty + "\n"
    + " totalDifficulty : " + block.totalDifficulty + "\n"
    + " extraData       : " + block.extraData + "\n"
    + " size            : " + block.size + "\n"
    + " gasLimit        : " + block.gasLimit + "\n"
    + " gasUsed         : " + block.gasUsed + "\n"
    + " timestamp       : " + block.timestamp + "\n"
    + " transactions    : " + block.transactions + "\n"
    + " uncles          : " + block.uncles);
    if (block.transactions != null) {
      console.log("--- transactions ---");
      block.transactions.forEach( function(e) {
        printTransaction(e);
      })
    }
}
```

**printUncle(block, uncleNumber, uncle)**

```
function printUncle(block, uncleNumber, uncle) {
  console.log("Block number     : " + block.number + " , uncle position: " + uncleNumber + "\n"
    + " Uncle number    : " + uncle.number + "\n"
    + " hash            : " + uncle.hash + "\n"
    + " parentHash      : " + uncle.parentHash + "\n"
    + " nonce           : " + uncle.nonce + "\n"
    + " sha3Uncles      : " + uncle.sha3Uncles + "\n"
    + " logsBloom       : " + uncle.logsBloom + "\n"
    + " transactionsRoot: " + uncle.transactionsRoot + "\n"
    + " stateRoot       : " + uncle.stateRoot + "\n"
    + " miner           : " + uncle.miner + "\n"
    + " difficulty      : " + uncle.difficulty + "\n"
    + " totalDifficulty : " + uncle.totalDifficulty + "\n"
    + " extraData       : " + uncle.extraData + "\n"
    + " size            : " + uncle.size + "\n"
    + " gasLimit        : " + uncle.gasLimit + "\n"
    + " gasUsed         : " + uncle.gasUsed + "\n"
    + " timestamp       : " + uncle.timestamp + "\n"
    + " transactions    : " + uncle.transactions + "\n");
}
```

**getMinedBlocks(miner, startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber)**

If `startBlockNumber` is not specified, it will default to the last 10,000 blocks. This takes some time to scan, so reduce this number to 1000 to reduce the scanning time.

If `endBlockNumber` is not specified, it will default to the latest block number.

```
function getMinedBlocks(miner, startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
  if (endBlockNumber == null) {
    endBlockNumber = eth.blockNumber;
    console.log("Using endBlockNumber: " + endBlockNumber);
  }
  if (startBlockNumber == null) {
    startBlockNumber = endBlockNumber - 10000;
    console.log("Using startBlockNumber: " + startBlockNumber);
  }
  console.log("Searching for miner \"" + miner + "\" within blocks "  + startBlockNumber + " and " + endBlockNumber + "\"");

  for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
      console.log("Searching block " + i);
    }
    var block = eth.getBlock(i);
    if (block != null) {
      if (block.miner == miner || miner == "*") {
        console.log("Found block " + block.number);
        printBlock(block);
      }
      if (block.uncles != null) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
          var uncle = eth.getUncle(i, j);
          if (uncle != null) {
            if (uncle.miner == miner || miner == "*") {
              console.log("Found uncle " + block.number + " uncle " + j);
              printUncle(block, j, uncle);
            }
          }          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**getMyMinedBlocks(startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber)**

```
function getMyMinedBlocks(startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
  getMinedBlocks(eth.accounts[0], startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber);
}
```

**Examples For Using The Function Above**

Here are some examples of using the above functions on the public mainnet Ethereum network.

- Print block mined by "0x52bc44d5378309ee2abf1539bf71de1b7d7be3b5". See https://etherscan.io/block/1325630

  ```
  getMinedBlocks("0x52bc44d5378309ee2abf1539bf71de1b7d7be3b5", 1325620, 1325640);
  ```
- Print block with uncles mined by "0xf3b9d2c81f2b24b0fa0acaaa865b7d9ced5fc2fb". See https://etherscan.io/block/1325635

  ```
  getMinedBlocks("0xf3b9d2c81f2b24b0fa0acaaa865b7d9ced5fc2fb", 1325630, 1325640);
  ```

  with the output:

  ```
  > getMinedBlocks("0xf3b9d2c81f2b24b0fa0acaaa865b7d9ced5fc2fb", 1325630, 1325640);
  Searching for miner "0xf3b9d2c81f2b24b0fa0acaaa865b7d9ced5fc2fb" within blocks 1325630 and 1325640"
  Found uncle 1325635 uncle 0
  Block number     : 1325635 , uncle position: 0
   Uncle number    : 1325634
   hash            : 0xae03bb2d5f1fbde4e22bf79850307ab6ae7d8545a9f0de4a5f529095546308c0
   parentHash      : 0x771b46e0310666780a55b1d603648d89e7d8cc3feac20a175117b4cb7e206a75
   nonce           : 0xeff5922de2f569e8
   sha3Uncles      : 0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347
   logsBloom       : 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   transactionsRoot: 0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421
   stateRoot       : 0xafca80bc836c00c7eeb4b6f3254573f72d38a0738ce4793da7d5222ed6c0c5cd
   miner           : 0xf3b9d2c81f2b24b0fa0acaaa865b7d9ced5fc2fb
   difficulty      : 26564802678158
   totalDifficulty : 0
   extraData       : 0x426974436c756220455448204d696e696e6720506f6f6c
   size            : 0
   gasLimit        : 4712388
   gasUsed         : 0
   timestamp       : 1460501836
   transactions    : undefined
  ```
- Print block with uncles. See https://etherscan.io/block/907703

  ```
  getMinedBlocks("*", 907703, 907703);
  ```
- Print blocks my miner has mined between blocks 1321603 and 1321605

  ```
  getMyMinedBlocks(1321603, 1321605);
  ```

Answer (score 2):

usually you would see it in the miner...

but if you would need it for a transaction purpose, I would suggest using this command

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetuncle

Comment: I need to do it from code.

Comment: wat do you mean "from code"? Like you need to know from Solidity? If so that's not possible. But the command I showed you above should work in JS...you'll have to hack it a bit but you'll be able to figure it out from that command I just linked you.

Comment: I meant 'programmatically', inside js code. When you said _'usually you would see it in the miner...'_ I thought you meant geth logs or something. Thanks for the link, I'll check it out along with the solution above.