# Block explorer running on private network

Tags: private-blockchain, explorers

Is there any application out there that allows me to explore the Ethereum blockchain in a private network? (something similar to what blockchain.info does to bitcoin or etherchain does to ethereum public network)

Answer (score 18):

I don't know of any block explorer source code / application you can deploy into your private network.

Here's my scripts to check and print blocks, uncles and transactions that can be used to explore blocks in your private network.

I've listed them separately for easier reading. If you intend to use it in `geth`, you would probably want to concatenate the following 5 functions into a single file for easy copy-pasting into the `geth` console.

**printTransaction(txHash)**

```
function printTransaction(txHash) {
  var tx = eth.getTransaction(txHash);
  if (tx != null) {
    console.log("  tx hash          : " + tx.hash + "\n"
      + "   nonce           : " + tx.nonce + "\n"
      + "   blockHash       : " + tx.blockHash + "\n"
      + "   blockNumber     : " + tx.blockNumber + "\n"
      + "   transactionIndex: " + tx.transactionIndex + "\n"
      + "   from            : " + tx.from + "\n" 
      + "   to              : " + tx.to + "\n"
      + "   value           : " + tx.value + "\n"
      + "   gasPrice        : " + tx.gasPrice + "\n"
      + "   gas             : " + tx.gas + "\n"
      + "   input           : " + tx.input);
  }
}
```

**printBlock(block)**

```
function printBlock(block) {
  console.log("Block number     : " + block.number + "\n"
    + " hash            : " + block.hash + "\n"
    + " parentHash      : " + block.parentHash + "\n"
    + " nonce           : " + block.nonce + "\n"
    + " sha3Uncles      : " + block.sha3Uncles + "\n"
    + " logsBloom       : " + block.logsBloom + "\n"
    + " transactionsRoot: " + block.transactionsRoot + "\n"
    + " stateRoot       : " + block.stateRoot + "\n"
    + " miner           : " + block.miner + "\n"
    + " difficulty      : " + block.difficulty + "\n"
    + " totalDifficulty : " + block.totalDifficulty + "\n"
    + " extraData       : " + block.extraData + "\n"
    + " size            : " + block.size + "\n"
    + " gasLimit        : " + block.gasLimit + "\n"
    + " gasUsed         : " + block.gasUsed + "\n"
    + " timestamp       : " + block.timestamp + "\n"
    + " transactions    : " + block.transactions + "\n"
    + " uncles          : " + block.uncles);
    if (block.transactions != null) {
      console.log("--- transactions ---");
      block.transactions.forEach( function(e) {
        printTransaction(e);
      })
    }
}
```

**printUncle(block, uncleNumber, uncle)**

```
function printUncle(block, uncleNumber, uncle) {
  console.log("Block number     : " + block.number + " , uncle position: " + uncleNumber + "\n"
    + " Uncle number    : " + uncle.number + "\n"
    + " hash            : " + uncle.hash + "\n"
    + " parentHash      : " + uncle.parentHash + "\n"
    + " nonce           : " + uncle.nonce + "\n"
    + " sha3Uncles      : " + uncle.sha3Uncles + "\n"
    + " logsBloom       : " + uncle.logsBloom + "\n"
    + " transactionsRoot: " + uncle.transactionsRoot + "\n"
    + " stateRoot       : " + uncle.stateRoot + "\n"
    + " miner           : " + uncle.miner + "\n"
    + " difficulty      : " + uncle.difficulty + "\n"
    + " totalDifficulty : " + uncle.totalDifficulty + "\n"
    + " extraData       : " + uncle.extraData + "\n"
    + " size            : " + uncle.size + "\n"
    + " gasLimit        : " + uncle.gasLimit + "\n"
    + " gasUsed         : " + uncle.gasUsed + "\n"
    + " timestamp       : " + uncle.timestamp + "\n"
    + " transactions    : " + uncle.transactions + "\n");
}
```

**getMinedBlocks(miner, startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber)**

If `startBlockNumber` is not specified, it will default to the last 10,000 blocks. This takes some time to scan, so reduce this number to 1000 to reduce the scanning time.

If `endBlockNumber` is not specified, it will default to the latest block number.

```
function getMinedBlocks(miner, startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
  if (endBlockNumber == null) {
    endBlockNumber = eth.blockNumber;
    console.log("Using endBlockNumber: " + endBlockNumber);
  }
  if (startBlockNumber == null) {
    startBlockNumber = endBlockNumber - 10000;
    console.log("Using startBlockNumber: " + startBlockNumber);
  }
  console.log("Searching for miner \"" + miner + "\" within blocks "  + startBlockNumber + " and " + endBlockNumber + "\"");

  for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
      console.log("Searching block " + i);
    }
    var block = eth.getBlock(i);
    if (block != null) {
      if (block.miner == miner || miner == "*") {
        console.log("Found block " + block.number);
        printBlock(block);
      }
      if (block.uncles != null) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
          var uncle = eth.getUncle(i, j);
          if (uncle != null) {
            if (uncle.miner == miner || miner == "*") {
              console.log("Found uncle " + block.number + " uncle " + j);
              printUncle(block, j, uncle);
            }
          }          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**getMyMinedBlocks(startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber)**

```
function getMyMinedBlocks(startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
  getMinedBlocks(eth.accounts[0], startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber);
}
```

**Examples For Using The Function Above**

Here are some examples of using the above functions on the public mainnet Ethereum network.

- Print block mined by "0x52bc44d5378309ee2abf1539bf71de1b7d7be3b5". See https://etherscan.io/block/1325630

  ```
  getMinedBlocks("0x52bc44d5378309ee2abf1539bf71de1b7d7be3b5", 1325620, 1325640);
  ```

  with the output being:

  ```
  getMinedBlocks("0x52bc44d5378309ee2abf1539bf71de1b7d7be3b5", 1325620, 1325640);
  Searching for miner "0x52bc44d5378309ee2abf1539bf71de1b7d7be3b5" within blocks 1325620 and 1325640"
  Found block 1325622
  Block number     : 1325622
   hash            : 0x06cdfceefb706514defc44a0bee28341bbb03e241a8bf8963d4c26b8a37f4309
   parentHash      : 0x2b29abc7a8cf63b40d33d8fcc6871d33e1ac1b7858d752d02f35b506981c15e3
   nonce           : 0x4f3215d189a40d32
   sha3Uncles      : 0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347
   logsBloom       : 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   transactionsRoot: 0xb7f7547bd977d3d8db65a1565035414c01058a82645cdde4b4bc00ceba0f8482
   stateRoot       : 0x10444688147ecdd6c838482141aa9d95af4816563faf05a8c6d8c0028abbb040
   miner           : 0x52bc44d5378309ee2abf1539bf71de1b7d7be3b5
   difficulty      : 26590795561548
   totalDifficulty : 13344340377114708239
   extraData       : 0xd783010305844765746887676f312e342e32856c696e7578
   size            : 770
   gasLimit        : 4712388
   gasUsed         : 42000
   timestamp       : 1460501661
   transactions    : 0x0fba1db5d970e41aa4c7b496631eb0a3dbaf2de46c7b27fda7800ed0145c609a,0x7891df53455629cfed4240f9c8a18a1657abfc088d47a1a89a51fc8ac339a2b1
   uncles          : 
  --- transactions ---
    tx hash          : 0x0fba1db5d970e41aa4c7b496631eb0a3dbaf2de46c7b27fda7800ed0145c609a
     nonce           : 23443
     blockHash       : 0x06cdfceefb706514defc44a0bee28341bbb03e241a8bf8963d4c26b8a37f4309
     blockNumber     : 1325622
     transactionIndex: 0
     from            : 0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8
     to              : 0x77d4d32435d57cbd99afd8ff4c9a58e0302e0675
     value           : 1503349049188321300
     gasPrice        : 20000000000
     gas             : 90000
     input           : 0x
    tx hash          : 0x7891df53455629cfed4240f9c8a18a1657abfc088d47a1a89a51fc8ac339a2b1
     nonce           : 23444
     blockHash       : 0x06cdfceefb706514defc44a0bee28341bbb03e241a8bf8963d4c26b8a37f4309
     blockNumber     : 1325622
     ...
  ```
- Print block with uncles mined by "0x4bb96091ee9d802ed039c4d1a5f6216f90f81b01". See https://etherscan.io/block/1325635

  ```
  getMinedBlocks("0x4bb96091ee9d802ed039c4d1a5f6216f90f81b01", 1325630, 1325640);
  ```
- Print block with uncles. See https://etherscan.io/block/907703

  ```
  getMinedBlocks("*", 907703, 907703);
  ```
- Print blocks my miner has mined between blocks 1321603 and 1321605

  ```
  getMyMinedBlocks(1321603, 1321605);
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Found this [etherparty/explorer](https://github.com/etherparty/explorer) and forked one this : https://github.com/carsenk/explorer. Not as good as etherscan but we can build from this. At-least enough for development purpose. Second one updated recently and UI is better.

Answer (score 4):

BlockScout is an open source blockchain explorer for EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine) based blockchains https://github.com/poanetwork/blockscout

Answer (score 2):

We're working on exactly this. It's called QuickBlocks. We're pre-alpha, but making excellent progress. PM me for more details. The difference between our solution and what you might find elsewhere is that QuickBlocks is fully decentralized. That is--it runs entirely on your own hard drive just like the Ethereum node. After an initial period of chacheing the data, it runs at 50-100 times faster than querying the RPC, fully parses all the transactions and generated events (if given an ABI), and generates the code needed to do that parsing automatically. We're getting ready to announce it as an alpha, but would welcome pre-alpha participation. Sorry for the plug, but the answer above is actually slightly incorrect.

Comment: Is it ready, we need one. Ready to contribute.

Comment: Not quite ready yet, but we're working on it.

Comment: I didn't find it. Please post a link to your source code.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this project it works on any chain as long as you provide an address to the RPC you want
https://github.com/Neufund/smart-contract-watch

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this project and I think it can do the work :

https://github.com/cubedro/eth-netstats

Comment: Eth-NetStats track network status of several nodes. It is not a block explorer.

Comment: good to know, I thought it would be possible to explore nodes with this tool but turns out I can just monitor the network. thank you for the headsup

Answer (score 1):

I'm building https://github.com/tryethernal/ethernal for this purpose, it's compatible with any EVM-based chains.

It's kind of open-source (BSL so you can do whatever you want except reselling it), so you can self host. There is also a hosted version with a free & premium plan.

Answer (score 0):

check out this for validate transaction also you can add your private node and validate https://etherscan.github.io/ethvalidate/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://github.com/blk-io/epirus-free nice UI, and stable