# How to create custom testnet like ropsten?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Is that possible to create a private testnet which can act like ropsten network.

i want to create a private net and i want to see all translation via online from etherscan.com

is that possible?

Comment: For the second part of your question, see [Block explorer running on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2919/block-explorer-running-on-private-network).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this Puppeth: https://blog.ethereum.org/2017/04/14/geth-1-6-puppeth-master/

> Geth 1.6 ships a new tool called puppeth, which aims to solve this particular pain point. Puppeth is a CLI wizard that aids in creating a new Ethereum network down to the genesis, bootnodes, signers, ethstats, faucet, dashboard and more, without the hassle that it would normally take to configure all these services one by one.

Here you get a live demo during Devcon3:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5RcjYPTG9g&list=PLaM7G4Llrb7xnKb_SeaKZ27opvaIjlBv5&index=1