# Generate rich list (Top Ethereum holders) using Geth/Web3

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I'm wondering if it's possible to generate a list of the top Ethereum holders, of the Public Ethereum MainNet, using Geth or Web3, but I'm not sure this is even feasible. Is there a way to do it? Can we interface with the database directly? Do we have to make a specialized script iterating through each block and comparing the inputs minus outputs?

Comment: Is there a better way to do this? Geth/Web3 is not a requirement

Comment: Do you want this for the Public Ethereum MainNet, or for a private Ethereum?

Comment: Cool, check my answer bellow and tell me if you need more details, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take this information directly from http://etherscan.io/accounts. You can read the html output programmatically and parse it.

Actually, EtherScan.io do lots of work for this. I recommend to take it as is. If you want to do something similar yourself, I think you have to query all all mining happen and all Ether transactions made and save it to off-chain database then you can query it.

Here is the accounts list from EtherScan.io:

[image]

---

Additionally, you can check for Tokens' Holders:

[image]

You can also have a graph for each Token's holders. For example you can check the top 500 of LEV (LeverJ):
https://etherscan.io/token/tokenholderchart/0x0f4ca92660efad97a9a70cb0fe969c755439772c?range=500
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I am still interested in making this myself but as you pointed out it will take some time

Answer (score 6):

[Presto-ethereum](https://github.com/xiaoyao1991/presto-ethereum) will enable you to query the blockchain using SQL

Comment: I messaged the creator of the library, and they said it's not possible to pull a list of addresses with Presto-ethereum. So I am still at a loss as to the best way to do this

Comment: Aw, sorry that's not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like, you'll have to iterate, but you could then save what you get to a relational database and make the information queryable (and for later blocks, only incrementally).

Check also out here [Block explorer running on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2919/block-explorer-running-on-private-network)
and here https://github.com/carsenk/explorer