# geth preload not working?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

I have been using the script provided in [this thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/how-to-make-miner-to-mine-only-when-there-are-pending-transactions/3152#3152) to mine only non-empty blocks in a private network by using the preload command when starting the geth node, as follows:

> geth --datadir ./Node1/ --preload './mineWhenNeeded.js'

However, recently I have noticed that my node is not mining automatically anymore (in other words, the preload option is not working).

However, if I attach a geth console to my node and load the script manually then it works fine, by using:

> loadScript('./mineWhenNeeded.js')

My node configuration is:

Geth 1.10.9, with Clique PoA consensus, and Ubuntu 20.04

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

It seems that this issue has been reported previously, but no answer was given, please [check here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/21190)

Thanks!