# What is the recommended replacement of the js option of the geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, pending-transactions

We were using the `js` together with a --preload to run geth in a private network using docker.
The main use-case was to mine blocks only when a transaction exists
(Similar to this [How to make miner to mine only when there are Pending Transactions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/how-to-make-miner-to-mine-only-when-there-are-pending-transactions) and this https://github.com/niksmac/ethereum-scripts/blob/master/src/mining-only-new-txs.js).
But now that the `js` is deprecated how can we achieve the same?
The only option we found so far, was to run `console` and use --preload.
Unfortunately, this requires us to also allow tty+std_open in docker which we would like to avoid.
Is there any way to do this?

This is very similar issue like this
[How to make miner to mine only when there are Pending Transactions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/how-to-make-miner-to-mine-only-when-there-are-pending-transactions) the question is how to achieve the same without a deprecated js option

Comment: Did you try redirecting the output to a file or /dev/null?

Comment: that's not an output, this is a console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible for now
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/26893