# How do I print my account balances and TheDAO tokens from geth

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, tokens, balances, the-dao

Is there a convenient script to print out my account balances and [TheDAO](https://daohub.org/) tokens from the go-ethereum client `geth`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `getAllBalances` Including TheDAO Tokens

Here's a version of `getAllBalances` that also displays [TheDAO](https://daohub.org/) tokens.

The following shell script works in the Linux and Mac environments where you are already running a `geth` instance that synch with the Ethereum blockchain.

This Unix shell script is based on the `checkAllBalances()` script from [Ethereum Frontier Guide - Listing accounts and checking balances](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/listing_accounts.html).

The JavaScript for `checkAllBalances()` is also available at [Common useful JavaScript snippets for geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth?lq=1).

You can customise the `geth attach` command to connect via IPC or RPC (eg: `geth attach rpc:http://192.168.1.52:8545`).

Create the file `$HOME/bin/getAllBalances` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

geth attach << EOF

function padTokens(s, n) {
  var o = s.toPrecision(n);
  while (o.length < n) {
    o = " " + o;
  }
  return o;
}

function padEthers(s) {
  var o = s.toFixed(18);
  while (o.length < 27) {
    o = " " + o;
  }
  return o;
}

function checkAllBalances() { 
  var theDAOABI = [ { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "", "value": "5e+22" } ], "name": "minTokensToCreate", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "", "value": "2.668900014413644230605979e+24" } ], "name": "totalSupply", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "", "value": "1464426000" } ], "name": "closingTime", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [], "name": "refund", "inputs": [], "constant": false }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "address", "name": "", "value": "0xda4a4626d3e16e094de3225a751aab7128e96526" } ], "name": "curator", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "balance", "value": "0" } ], "name": "balanceOf", "inputs": [ { "type": "address", "name": "_owner" } ], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "_numberOfProposals", "value": "0" } ], "name": "numberOfProposals", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "address", "name": "", "value": "0x807640a13483f8ac783c557fcdf27be11ea4ac7a" } ], "name": "extraBalance", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "bool", "name": "", "value": true } ], "name": "isFueled", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "bool", "name": "success" } ], "name": "createTokenProxy", "inputs": [ { "type": "address", "name": "_tokenHolder" } ], "constant": false }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "_voteID" } ], "name": "vote", "inputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "_proposalID" }, { "type": "bool", "name": "_supportsProposal" } ], "constant": false }, { "type": "event", "name": "FuelingToDate", "inputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "value", "indexed": false } ], "anonymous": false }, { "type": "event", "name": "ProposalAdded", "inputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "proposalID", "indexed": true }, { "type": "address", "name": "recipient", "indexed": false }, { "type": "uint256", "name": "amount", "indexed": false }, { "type": "bool", "name": "newCurator", "indexed": false }, { "type": "string", "name": "description", "indexed": false } ], "anonymous": false }, { "type": "event", "name": "ProposalTallied", "inputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "proposalID", "indexed": true }, { "type": "bool", "name": "result", "indexed": false }, { "type": "uint256", "name": "quorum", "indexed": false } ], "anonymous": false } ];
  var theDAOAddress = "0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413";
  var theDAO = eth.contract(theDAOABI).at(theDAOAddress);
  var theDAOTotal = 0; 
  var ethersTotal = 0; 

  console.log("  #     Account                                        TheDAO                      ethers");
  console.log("------- ------------------------------------------ ---------- ---------------------------");
  var i =0; 
  eth.accounts.forEach( function(e){
    var tokens = theDAO.balanceOf(e) / parseFloat(1e16);
    theDAOTotal += parseFloat(tokens);
    var ethers = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(e), "ether");
    ethersTotal += parseFloat(ethers);
    console.log("  " + i + "\t" + e + " " + padTokens(tokens, 10) + " " + padEthers(ethers)); 
    i++; 
  })
  console.log("------- ------------------------------------------ ---------- ---------------------------");
  console.log("  " + i + "                                               " + padTokens(theDAOTotal, 10) + " " + padEthers(ethersTotal));
}; 

checkAllBalances()

exit;

EOF
```

Set the executable bit for this file using the command:

```
chmod 700 $HOME/bin/getAllBalances
```

Run the script using the command `getAllBalances` or `$HOME/bin/getAllBalances` to produce the following type of output:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ getAllBalances
instance: Geth/v1.3.6/linux/go1.5.1
 datadir: /home/user/.ethereum
coinbase: 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
at block: 1482591 (Mon, 09 May 2016 10:09:37 AEST)
modules: admin:1.0 db:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 shh:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
undefined
undefined
undefined
  #     Account                                        TheDAO                      ethers
------- ------------------------------------------ ---------- ---------------------------
  0     0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa       1100        1.111111111111111111
  1     0xbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb       2200        2.222222222222222222
  2     0xcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc       3300        3.333333333333333333
------- ------------------------------------------ ---------- ---------------------------
  3                                                      6600        6.666666666666666666
undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

## `getAllBalances` For Ethers Only

The following shell script works in the Linux and Mac environments where you are already running a `geth` instance that synch with the Ethereum blockchain.

This Unix shell script uses the `checkAllBalances()` script from [Ethereum Frontier Guide - Listing accounts and checking balances](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/listing_accounts.html).

You can customise the `geth attach` command to connect via IPC or RPC (eg: `geth attach rpc:http://192.168.1.52:8545`).

Create the file `$HOME/bin/getAllBalances` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

geth attach << EOF

function checkAllBalances() { 
  var i =0; 
  var total = 0.0;
  eth.accounts.forEach( function(e){
    total += parseFloat(eth.getBalance(e));
    console.log("  eth.accounts["+i+"]: " +  e + " \tbalance: " +
      web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(e), "ether") + " ether"); 
    i++; 
  })
  console.log("total: " + web3.fromWei(total), "ether");
}; 

checkAllBalances()

exit;

EOF
```

Set the executable bit for this file using the command:

```
chmod 700 $HOME/bin/getAllBalances
```

Run the script using the command `getAllBalances` or `$HOME/bin/getAllBalances` to produce the following type of output:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ getAllBalances 
instance: Geth/v1.3.6/linux/go1.5.1
 datadir: /home/user/.ethereum
coinbase: 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
at block: 1454325 (Wed, 04 May 2016 17:33:00 AEST)
modules: admin:1.0 db:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 shh:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
undefined
  eth.accounts[0]: 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa   balance: 1.11111111111111111 ether
  eth.accounts[1]: 0xbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   balance: 2.22222222222222222 ether
  eth.accounts[2]: 0xcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc   balance: 3.33333333333333333 ether
total: 6.666666666666 ether
undefined

user@Kumquat:~$
```