# Iterating over all public values of a mapping in web3

Tags: web3js, contract-design, mapping

Let's assume we have the standard token contract with balances:

```
 mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
```

If I want to know balances of all addresses (who have ever transacted with the contract) in web3, can I somehow construct this state? I.e. I don't know the addresses themselves to call `balanceOf(address)` to start iterating?

Comment: See this: [uint mapping where it is possible to iterate over all keys](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/library/iterable_mapping.sol).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't iterate over the key of `balanceOf` as the data stored in the mapping to represent the key is the sha3 of the specified key. From [Solidity In Depth - Mappings](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#mappings),

> The key data is not actually stored in a mapping, only its sha3 hash used to look up the value.

You could instead use the following script to find all transaction made to the account.

```
function getAddressesSentToAccount(myaccount, startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
  if (endBlockNumber == null) {
    endBlockNumber = eth.blockNumber;
    console.log("Using endBlockNumber: " + endBlockNumber);
  }
  if (startBlockNumber == null) {
    startBlockNumber = endBlockNumber - 1000;
    console.log("Using startBlockNumber: " + startBlockNumber);
  }
  console.log("Searching for transactions to account \"" + myaccount + "\" within blocks "  + startBlockNumber + " and " + endBlockNumber + "\"");

  for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
      console.log("Searching block " + i);
    }
    var block = eth.getBlock(i, true);
    if (block != null && block.transactions != null) {
      block.transactions.forEach( function(e) {
        if (myaccount == e.to) {
          console.log(e.blockNumber + " " + e.from + " " + web3.fromWei(e.value, "ether"));
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

To view the addresses that sent some ethers to [TheDAO](https://daohub.org/index.html) in the last 1000 blocks:

```
> getAddressesSentToAccount("0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413")
```

And the output will resemble:

```
Searching for transactions to account "0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413" within blocks 1485458 and 1486458"
1485461 0x0903d814bceff7efa3e91a238271f60bb0ab05bf 34
1485461 0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98 10
1485462 0x924c251902924c7dbd4cbf166d42757fb2d146cb 70
1485465 0xdf6a69f1c0a7962113cff9e70101cec77d5fde9d 25.08851818
1485466 0x14afd9a49285d62bc8fd33fc94c1b7c98437e0c9 105
1485480 0xe9de5262a6c3cc173421f46ae1356c9b6f9b7355 10
...
```

To view the addresses that sent some ethers to [TheDAO](https://daohub.org/index.html) between blocks 1486400 and 1486410:

```
> getAddressesSentToAccount("0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413", 1486400, 1486410)
```

And the output will resemble:

```
Searching for transactions to account "0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413" within blocks 1486400 and 1486410"
1486400 0x8662bdb16c4d6eb080b45be3a5be80cc9511aac1 99
1486402 0xd0a886e00bee1aa3532182d382012697851edcd0 5
1486402 0xbd5a8c94bd8be6470644f70c8f8a33a8a55c6341 195
1486404 0x919c066b79d62581482b0ea0f11339b73ddb3dbd 8
1486406 0xd69104404a21cf359985c21988b959ace3880c83 11
1486408 0x24602a569f51e64bd54ad335be2e3f53ea9ef689 10
1486408 0x2bd46878a4b95e4299324b93afde2bd4281a8fc7 6.02962455
undefined
```

And [How do I print my account balances and TheDAO tokens from geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3570/how-do-i-print-my-account-balances-and-thedao-tokens-from-geth) will show you how you can get the balance of an account from a token contract like TheDAO.

Comment: Ok. This is very in-depth and good answers. However, because it's standard token contract, I can iterate over all events which are accessible through `eth_getLogs`.