# How do I get a list of accounts from my Ledger Nano S wallet, including unused accounts?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, ledger-nano-s, hardware-wallets

[`geth` lists the non-zero balance accounts and the next zero balance account from your Ledger Nano](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6971pc/geth_161_deripors_of_ohratuu_hint_may_4th_released/dh5ma9u/).

How can I get a list of accounts from my Ledger Nano S wallet, including the next block of unused accounts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `geth` JavaScript Version

The following `geth` JavaScript will list a block of accounts, both used and unused, from your Ledger Nano S:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// List accounts from the Ledger Nano S
//
// (c) BokkyPooBah - Aug 13 2017. The MIT Licence.
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function padLeft(s, n) {
  var result = s.toString();
  while (result.length < n) {
    result = " " + result;
  }
  return result;
}

function listNanoAccounts(from, to) {
  if (from == null) {
    from = 0;
  }
  if (to == null) {
    to = 9;
  }
  var nanoUrl=personal.listWallets[personal.listWallets.length-1].url;
  var nanoPathPrefix="m/44'/60'/0'/";
  var total = new BigNumber(0);
  console.log("  # Account                                                        Ethers");
  console.log("--- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------");
  for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    var account = personal.deriveAccount(nanoUrl, nanoPathPrefix + i, true).address;
    var weis = eth.getBalance(account);
    var balance = web3.fromWei(weis, "ether");
    total = total.add(balance);
    console.log(padLeft(i, 3) + " " + account + " " + padLeft(balance.toFixed(18), 26));
  }
  console.log("--- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------");
  console.log("    Total                                      " + padLeft(total, 26));
  console.log("--- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------");
}

listNanoAccounts()
```

---

### Command Line Script Option

The script above can be modified to be run from the command line:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# List accounts from the Ledger Nano S
#
# Works in OS/X and Linux. May work in Windows with Cygwin.
#
# How to use:
# 1. Save into a file, e.g., ~/bin/getNanoAccounts
# 2. Set the executable bit - `chmod 700 ~/bin/getNanoAccounts`
# 3. Run the script - `~/bin/getNanoAccounts`
#
# (c) BokkyPooBah - Aug 13 2017. The MIT Licence.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

geth attach << EOF | grep "RESULT: " | sed "s/RESULT: //"

function padLeft(s, n) {
  var result = s.toString();
  while (result.length < n) {
    result = " " + result;
  }
  return result;
}

function listNanoAccounts(from, to) {
  if (from == null) {
    from = 0;
  }
  if (to == null) {
    to = 9;
  }
  var nanoUrl=personal.listWallets[personal.listWallets.length-1].url;
  var nanoPathPrefix="m/44'/60'/0'/";
  var total = new BigNumber(0);
  console.log("RESULT:   # Account                                                        Ethers");
  console.log("RESULT: --- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------");
  for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    var account = personal.deriveAccount(nanoUrl, nanoPathPrefix + i, true).address;
    var weis = eth.getBalance(account);
    var balance = web3.fromWei(weis, "ether");
    total = total.add(balance);
    console.log("RESULT: " + padLeft(i, 3) + " " + account + " " + padLeft(balance.toFixed(18), 26));
  }
  console.log("RESULT: --- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------");
  console.log("RESULT:     Total                                      " + padLeft(total, 26));
  console.log("RESULT: --- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------");
}

listNanoAccounts()

EOF
```

Following is some sample output:

```
Iota:bin bokkypoobah$ ~/bin/getNanoAccounts
  # Account                                                        Ethers
--- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------
  0 0x1234567890000000000000000000000000000000       1.111111111111111111
  1 0x1234567891111111111111111111111111111111       2.222222222222222222
  2 0x1234567891111111111111111111111111111112       0.000000000000000000
  3 0x1234567891111111111111111111111111111113       0.000000000000000000
  4 0x1234567891111111111111111111111111111114       0.000000000000000000
  5 0x1234567891111111111111111111111111111115       0.000000000000000000
  6 0x1234567891111111111111111111111111111116       0.000000000000000000
  7 0x1234567891111111111111111111111111111117       0.000000000000000000
  8 0x1234567891111111111111111111111111111118       0.000000000000000000
  9 0x1234567891111111111111111111111111111119       0.000000000000000000
--- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------
    Total                                            3.333333333333333333
--- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------
```

See also [How do I print my account balances and TheDAO tokens from geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3570/how-do-i-print-my-account-balances-and-thedao-tokens-from-geth) which can be extended to any ERC20 tokens.