# How can I write a script to move ETH from many wallets associated with a mnemonic to a single wallet?

Tags: myetherwallet, hd-wallets

Would be grateful to be pointed to any resources that would allow me to do this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first parse all the accounts in your HD wallet.

For example, if you have a **[Ledger Nano](https://www.ledgerwallet.com/)**, there is a script **[here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-accounts-from-my-ledger-nano-s-wallet-including-unused-a/#answer-24236)**.

Or you can just generate addresses from a predefined mnemonic with `ethereumjs-wallet` as described **[here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33395/what-is-a-hd-wallet-for-ether-and-how-to-create-one-using-nodejs/#answer-33440)**.

Finally, once you have the **Nth** address generated by the HD wallet you can just use:

`web3.eth.sendTransaction ( { from: nthaddress, to: singleaddress, value: web3.eth.getBalanceOf( nthaddress ) - fee } )`

to do the transaction

where `nthaddress` is the `deriveAccount` with the path `m/xx'/yy'/0'/..` ( e.g.: `"m/44'/60'/0'/0/0"` )

Comment: Thank you so much, Andrei!  I'm attempting this, but am hitting the following error:  CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node https://mainnet.infura.io.
    at Object.InvalidConnection (/home/ubuntu/server/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:31:16)
    at HttpProvider.send (/home/ubuntu/server/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:87:18)
    at Eth.send [as getBalance] (/home/ubuntu/server/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:58)
    ....etc. Could you advise?  I'm quite new; apologies if the solution is obvious.

Comment: I don't know much about `infura.io` , all I can suggest is to run your own node (eventually a light node like this https://redd.it/6lzw8y ), sorry...