# How to read the ETH value and other token values from an account?

Tags: web3js, tokens, accounts, nodejs

Let's say I've created an account using this code as explained in docs:

```
web3.eth.accounts.create();
> {
    address: "0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cDe8e3bBed6568B2Fa01",
    privateKey: "0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}
```

How do I connect (unlock) to that account later and see all the ETH and other tokens it contains?

Comment: Not to toot my own horn, but I wrote a [tutorial in Web3 to get the ETH Balance of an Ethereum Address](http://shawntabrizi.com/crypto/ethereum-web3-js-hello-world-get-eth-balance-ethereum-address/). Working on another right now to get the ERC-20 Token balance for addresses too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the Ether Balance use `web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(acct), "ether")`

The following links might give a guide on checking token balance.

http://nuclearcryptobuddha.blog/2017/06/how-to-send-receive-and-check-balance-of-erc20-tokens-using-geth/

https://lightrains.com/blogs/useful-ethereum-geth-javascript-snippets

[How do I print my account balances and TheDAO tokens from geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3570/how-do-i-print-my-account-balances-and-thedao-tokens-from-geth)

I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. A few things aren't clear to me yet. 1) Once I create an account I get a private key and an encryption method. Should I use the encrypt method on the spot and save its result to use later? 2) when I unlock the account, you mentioned a password, but what about the private key? 3) how do I connect the two commands you wrote together? Does personal.unlockAccount return an 'eth' object?

Comment: you have to store the key in local storage encrypted using a password and decrypt with the password when needed to sign a transaction. here https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#eth-accounts-signtransaction  to sign a transaction you need only the private key and no password. You use the password to store the private key in secure. as doc says >privateKey - string:This should never be shared or stored unencrypted in localstorage!

Comment: unlocking an account means getting the private key to sign data or transactions .

Comment: Not yet, I cannot test it yet since I'm stuck in an earlier step, as you can see here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30245/invalid-json-rpc-response-undefined

Comment: Yes I have, but I cannot test it yet, since I'm stuck in another earlier step, as you can see here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30275/server-resources-needed-to-run-geth-part2

Comment: I've deleted this question because I solved it by myself. Now I face with another problem, I will test your code as soon as I get my program run at all.

Comment: I have not tested it yet. Yesterday I just managed to solve another problem I'd had: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30296/web3-accounts-create-is-not-a-function/30302?noredirect=1#comment32423_30302

Comment: While trying to adopt the suggested answer, I came across a very tough problem which I had to open a bounty on SO for. I also had some troubles to adopt the suggested answer in that question, but yesterday I've finally made it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256033/tracker-error-trk0005-failed-to-locate-cl-exe-the-system-cannot-find-the/47304700?noredirect=1#comment81836873_47304700

Comment: OK I've tested it. web3.eth.getBalance(address) throws an error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""