# Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined

Tags: web3js, accounts, nodejs

I'm trying to create an account through Node.js. This is my code:

```
export async function createNewAccount() {
    var web3Instance =  new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    return web3Instance.eth.accounts.create();
}
```

But I'm getting the following error (from 'create' function):

> Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined

I have installed web3.js in my project.

What other step have I missed?

BTW opening the browser on address "http://localhost:8545" returns 404. Is there anything I need to install in order to make it work? Is that the testrpc?

Notice that I want to work against the real blockchain, not a test one.

**Edit:**

As suggested by Karthikeyan, I downloaded and started geth. I don't know if it's actually working, it looks like this:

[image]

But I keep getting the same error when I try to create an account.

Comment: Have you started Local Blockchain in your system with geth command

Comment: @KarthikeyanThangavel no I haven't. A local blockchain is a test one? Because I want to work with the real one. Additionally, if I use Node.js should I use Geth? I thought Geth is for Go lang.

Comment: You have start geth in your local system with rpc commands, else you can't communicate with the main Blockchain .

Comment: @KarthikeyanThangavel are you sure it's geth and not something else? Because the 'g' in 'geth' stands for Go lang, but I don't use Go, I use Node.js.

Comment: Without syncing blockchain in your local system, you cant do any operation blockchain.

Comment: use geth to sync blockchain in your local system

Comment: @KarthikeyanThangavel yes I understand, but is geth the right thing for me EVEN THOUGH I DON'T USE GO LANG, I USE NODE.JS? Perhaps there is an equivalent for Node.js?

Comment: If you want to communicate with Ethereum Main net then you have to use either geth, pygeth, else you cant. If you want to test your code you can use ethereumjs-testrpc package

Comment: @KarthikeyanThangavel OK, good. So how do I start geth in my local system? If it's too long to explain, you can refer me to an external article.

Comment: Refer this link https://www.ethereum.org/cli

Comment: @KarthikeyanThangavel I started geth, not sure if it's working correctly, you can see in my edited post. Anyway I keep getting the same error when I try to create an account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have started geth with the code like below, that means its a test network (rinkeby)

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=2048  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

Even if you have started without `--rinkeby` you must have mentioned the other parameters like `--rpc`,`--rpcapi` and all other to work with the web3.js

Comment: I don't want to use a test network. I want the real one. What parameters should I place?

Comment: Remove `--rinkeby` from the above line and execute it. But better try it on a test network before you do on a real one