# web3.eth basic functionality

Tags: web3js, ether, nodejs

I'm just trying to get web3.eth in node.js to tell me what the current block number is but I get an error 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""', I have "geth --syncmode "light"" running in a different console tab and I thought that would be all I needed to get a data feed from the main-net, is there something I'm just not understanding or is it something about my environment that is causing this

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8545");
web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log);
```

node v14.4.0

npm v6.14.5

"dependencies": {

```
"ethereumjs-testrpc": "^6.0.3",
"web3": "^1.2.9",
"web3-eth": "^1.2.9"
```

}

Comment: Have you set up an Ethereum node (Geth, Parity, Ganache, etc) running on your local machine and listening on port 8545?

Comment: yes I have a geth "light" client running and by default, it listens to port 8545

Comment: @RileyDesrochers See this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30245/invalid-json-rpc-response-undefined. RPC api is disable by default, you have to explicitly enable if you intend to use it.

Answer (score 0):

the error is caused because you don't have enabled the HTTP-RPC server.

To enable it you can add the `--rpc` option to the `geth --syncmode "light"` command.

Also you can decide which API enable by listing them in the `--rpcapi` option.