# web3.accounts.create() is not a function

Tags: web3js, accounts, nodejs

I want to create a new account via code (Node.js), so I ran the following code, which was copy-pasted from the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html):

```
web3.eth.accounts.create();
```

How ever accounts' value is an empty array, and therefore I'm getting this error:

> web3.eth.accounts.create is not a function

which makes sense because `Array` doesn't have a method named `create`.

How do I create a new account?

Comment: which web3 version are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js

`web3.personal.newAccount('mynewaccount', function(err, res){

            console.log("error"+err);
            console.log("res"+res);

        });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using web3 version prior to 1.0.
as i know `web3.eth.accounts.create()` was introduced in web3 1.0. so check your web3js version. if you have a prior version use `web3.eth.personal.newAccount(password, [callback])`
 documented [here](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#newaccount)

Comment: For some reason npm installs version 0.20.2 by default. In that version the right command is neither of the above but: web3.personal.newAccount(password, [callback]). What a DLL hell! What would you recommend me to do? Use my current version or upgrade to 1.0 (if it's possible at all)

Comment: try npm install web3@1.0.0-beta.24

Comment: it throws stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

Comment: this is a nodejs issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365714/nodejs-error-installing-with-npm

Answer (score 1):

separate the "password" and "callback result" arguments of each other

```
web3.eth.personal.newAccount(password,(result)=>{
    console.log(result);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));        
});
```