# Both web3.eth.accounts.create() and web3.eth.personal.newAccount() not working

Tags: web3js, dapps, accounts, react, dapp-design

I'm making a dApp on reactjs. I wanted to create a new account and have done it trying 2 methods

1. `this.web3.eth.personal.newAccount()`
2. `this.web3.eth.accounts.create()`

I have attached the code below(ignore the comments)

```
 OTPSubmit(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     //alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
     this.setState({
        showComponent: true,
       account: this.web3.eth.personal.newAccount()
       #account: this.web3.eth.accounts.create()
     });

   }
```

These are the errors I'm getting

1. web3.eth.accounts.create() is not a function
2. Cannot read property 'newAccount' of undefined

Can you please help me? I am very new to this

Answer (score 1):

if you are using web3.js 1.0.0, try giving a password in the parameters like this:

> web3.personal.newAccount(newPassword);

if you are using an older version, try to separate "password" and "callback result" arguments like "Hamid Jolany" mentionned in this [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30296/web3-accounts-create-is-not-a-function):

> web3.eth.personal.newAccount(password,(result)=>{
>      console.log(result);
>      res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
>   });

Comment: is newPassword a variable here?

Comment: You can use a string or a variable.
Which version are you using?