# Listing transactions in a private blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, private-blockchain, javascript, query

In a private blockchain, is it possible to list the transactions based on *from* and *to* parameters in a transaction.

Is it possible to check the latest transaction *from* or *to* an address?

Also, is it possible to check the time of a specific transaction?

Since all this data is in the blockchain, can we do this through the javacsript console in geth?

Comment: Related: [Common useful javascript snippets for geth](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [`web3.ETH.filter`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter)

Parameters

String|Object - The string "latest" or "pending" to watch for changes in the latest block or pending transactions respectively. Or a filter options object as follows:

1. `String|Object` - The string `"latest"` or `"pending"` to watch for changes in the latest block or pending transactions respectively. Or a filter options object as follows:

   - `fromBlock`: `Number|String` - The number of the earliest block (`latest` may be given to mean the most recent and `pending` currently mining, block). By default `latest`.
   - `toBlock`: `Number|String` - The number of the latest block (`latest` may be given to mean the most recent and `pending` currently mining, block). By default `latest`.
   - `address`: `String` - An address or a list of addresses to only get logs from particular account(s).
   - `topics`: `Array of Strings` - An array of values which must each appear in the log entries. The order is important, if you want to leave topics out use `null`, e.g. `[null, '0x00...']`. You can also pass another array for each topic with options for that topic e.g. `[null, ['option1', 'option2']]`

EG:

```
// watch for changes 

var filter = web3.ETH.filter({address: "0xYOURADDRESS"});

filter.watch(function(error, result){
  if (!error)
    console.log(result);
});
```

[Link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3478/2460) for the script (not filter) to get the transactions to/from an account.

[Issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1897) in the Go-ethereum github to implement this functionality (`eth.listTransactions`) by default.

Latest update from Ethereum Developers:

> Locking this issue but leaving it open.
>
> We're considering a suitable implementation for this feature.
>
> No ETA.