# pyethapp fails to send transactions in a private net

Tags: transactions, mining, pyethapp, pyethereum, raw-transaction

This question is related to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/listing-transactions-in-a-private-blockchain) question but I'm using the **pyethapp** client instead of **web3.js**.

I've created two accounts using **pyetahpp**:

```
pyethapp account new # 1
pyethapp account new # 2
```

and then launched **pyethapp** on a private test net in console mode. I made a transaction:

```
In [6]: acct_service = eth.services.accounts   
In [7]: acct1 = acct_service.accounts[0]
In [8]: acct2 = acct_service.accounts[1]
In [9]: acct1.unlock('')
In [10]: acct2.unlock('')
In [11]:  acct_service.accounts
Out[11]: 
[<Account(address=a741c1ad30bfc3d4f16435e9d32ddb31198ed487, id=None)>,
 <Account(address=bdce83daac449aa98446e1a0d3b9f95eff53cf02, id=None)>]
In [12]: tx = eth.transact('bdce83daac449aa98446e1a0d3b9f95eff53cf02', value=100)
In [13]: eth.find_transaction(tx)
Out[14]: {}
In [15]: INFO:pow.subprocess    nonce found 
INFO:pow.subprocess sending nonce 
In [16]: eth.find_transaction(tx)




In [15]: eth.find_transaction(tx)
Out[15]: {}
```

Why can't I see the transaction? There is only one node that is running in the testnet and it is also mining. From what I've seen, **pyethapp** stops mining once launched in console mode (with the **--console** flag after run).

Comment: Have you solved the problem?
I also meet this problem that the transaction which is made in pyethapp can not be written in block in Geth in my private chain.

Comment: I am also facing same issue.Did you resolved it????