# Checking the blockchain within Solidity contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I want my contract to check a given range of blocks and see whether there are any transactions between a given pair of addresses. Is this possible to do in Solidity? Otherwise how would I do it?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/

Comment: More info: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, its not possible the EVM is pretty isolated. Alternative way is to watch the blockchain with a `web3.js` script and notify your contract. Of course this is a potential security hole.
The [opcodes of the EVM](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119/what-opcodes-are-available-for-the-ethereum-evm) do only have limited access to the current block.

Answer (score 3):

If those two addresses are contracts, they could be coded to inform a "watching" contract of any interactions. Unfortunately, they would have to be specifically programmed to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in my case, the two addresses are not contracts.