# Can a smart contract see the blockchain history?

Tags: contract-development, transactions

Is it possible for smart contract to view past transactions done on it, in other words would it be possible for a smart contract to see who has sent it Ether since its inception?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/checking-the-blockchain-within-solidity-contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible only if you had registred them (in a map for example). the smart contract hasn't the ability to explore the blockchain to know has a log of the transaction senders.

Comment: That is what I suspected. I am trying to write contract that accepts ETH and after a set date will allocate tokens to those, but as wel all know the fallback function cant do much (not even a save to a gloabl map) with a send().

Comment: @RFVenter The contract could have a buyTokens payable function that checks the block number or timestamp and then allocates tokens.