# How run queries on the block chain?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, query

since I am quite new to Eth I have the following question : there are some transactions made between two parties which are saved in the block chain. On window.onload() prior to rendering my components, I would like to run a query on it in order to get the transactions out from the block chain, without going into too much detail about the hashes or blocknumber/index. Is there a way I can do that and if yes, where can I read about it in the docu ???

All I need to get is an Object with props like to : and from : so I can display these in my html.

Cheers!

Evgeni

Comment: This might help: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3478/259

Comment: Can you also look at this question of mine and let me have your opinion, thanks!   http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6158/best-practice-for-getting-transactions-on-reload

Answer (score 1):

We're working on software that allows you to export transactions from any number of different accounts into various formats including databases. Check it out here: http://ethslurp.com. It works as a back-end scaper. You can set it up in a cron job to keep the data fresh.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.