# pyethapp is unable to add transactions to blockchain

Tags: transactions, blockchain, synchronization, private-blockchain, pyethapp

I'm using **pyethapp** and **web3.js** to make transactions on a private network.

```
var to = "1152a50b91887591a2447b233105f392dbae72ce";
var from = "4dfd7cb92bca796821d5fc4512a6a02cc98d833d";
var json_data = {"Hi!" : "Hello World!!!"};
var tx_hash = web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: from_addr, to: to_addr, value: web3.toWei(10000, 'wei'), data: web3.toHex(json_data), gas:90000});
```

Everything goes well and the transaction is being signed by pyethapp. However, the transaction is not added to the blockchain. The output when it's signed is the following in the console (while running pyethapp):

```
INFO:p2p.peermgr    waiting for bootstrap 
INFO:pow.subprocess nonce found 
INFO:pow.subprocess sending nonce 
INFO:pow    nonce found mining_hash=ddcb1d6ad36c172fe077f0cbf4b7e889339ba8effbcbc9472866e8ac9c4724e1
INFO:pow.subprocess nonce found 
INFO:pow.subprocess sending nonce 
INFO:pow    nonce found mining_hash=c32c7a78781a65cab4fa9b5d9faa6926fc58b626fa7fa88d351f629228dfb379
INFO:pow.subprocess nonce found 
INFO:pow.subprocess sending nonce 
INFO:pow    nonce found mining_hash=697a2cb3c9b07e97114eca5eb0077258d05ce8b6d1a6f528083f3c768d6880fc
INFO:pow.subprocess nonce found 
INFO:pow.subprocess sending nonce 
INFO:pow    nonce found mining_hash=7a7697bfd0416b29360a2fb675b8c760aa8b90a54dde307cbde91e4c0cd3d8e1
INFO:pow.subprocess nonce found 
INFO:pow.subprocess sending nonce 
INFO:pow    nonce found mining_hash=8f19ee2ee4d8814ec9c172037d274f3a7f9df28b32a7e585610969dd06c240ed
INFO:accounts   signing tx account=<Account(address=4dfd7cb92bca796821d5fc4512a6a02cc98d833d, id=None)> tx=<Transaction(7236)>
INFO:pow.subprocess nonce found 
INFO:pow.subprocess sending nonce 
INFO:pow    nonce found mining_hash=19f3d9615f961c7a2351a2460393476f22ddbaa79bbfe3bac3acd3eedab14676
WARNING:pow mining_hash does not match 
INFO:pow.subprocess nonce found 
INFO:pow.subprocess sending nonce 
INFO:pow    nonce found mining_hash=4daad5461707f1c29fc88c5929fd5c50b423159601181587e89d189d5f50329d
```

I also noticed the line:

```
mining_hash=19f3d9615f961c7a2351a2460393476f22ddbaa79bbfe3bac3acd3eedab14676
    WARNING:pow mining_hash does not match
```

I'm not sure it's related to the transaction (I've made only one transaction on the private net). All addresses have predefined balances inside the blockchain and it's not an issue related to insufficient gas/Ether.

The genesis block is also using a very low difficulty level (<100) in order to mine transactions more rapidly.

Why isn't the transaction added to the block chain?

I'm using the function (from [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth/3478#3478)) to query the blockchain for the recipient's address.

**Edit**:

What's strange is that the transaction has a receipt:

```
blockHash:"0x10b5c028b21e42104de61ba943ce14d11bcf01812ec675b10373d80316da481"
blockNumber:2
contractAddress:null
cumulativeGasUsed:21952
gasUsed:21952
logs:Array[0]
transactionHash:"0xcbd5db525f2b592d3d16f332747f22c50f1632e5629f5fe497673efc5d2b7a5a"
transactionIndex:0
```

Comment: `gas:90000` isn't that high and I'd try `gas:3000000` during debugging.

Comment: I've increased the amount of gas but I still don't see the transaction in the blockchain. The warning message doesn't show anymore.

Comment: It's pretty weird since the transaction has a receipt. Doesn't it confirm that the transaction actually took place and is/should be stored inside the blockchain? I'm using a more generous value for the gas limit 30000000000.

Comment: Yes, the receipt says the transaction is in block 2 so it is in the blockchain.  Separately, the `gas` value you specify should be lower than the gas limit of the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially `gas:90000` was too low.  After increasing it, the receipt indicates that the transaction is now in the blockchain, block #2.

Comment: It turned out that the block query function was broken :))