# web3 filter option not working

Tags: web3js, filters

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter({fromBlock: 350000, toBlock: 'latest',address:"0x075da4ebae466b80d451b0627296d5d38b3e99c1"});

var myResults1 = filter.watch(function (error, log) {

   console.log(error); 
   console.log(log); 
 });

filter.get(function(error, result){ console.log(error, result); });
```

The above code always shows empty result. What is the problem?

If I change like this it returns nothing:

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter({fromBlock: 350000, toBlock: 'latest'});
filter.get(function(error, result){ console.log(error, result); });
```

I need to get the transactions details by the account if there another option please give that idea.

Comment: I think you're looking for this - http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3478/2460

Comment: facing same problem