# Can you fetch the whole transaction history of specific contracts somewhere?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, query, api

I know you can validate the data of specific tx hashes using web3js or the etherscan api.
But is there a service which allows to query all transactions performed by or connected to a specific smart contract?

Comment: Please refer to https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16112/how-to-obtain-all-transaction-of-a-contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to fetch specific contracts (or to an extent general account) address history, then you can use service such as Moralis.

They have Transaction API that can help you index transaction data easily. If you like to index historical transactions, they have an API [here](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-wallet-transactions) that you can use very easily. All you need to provide is a valid `address` input.

Here if you like to follow a tutorial, they also have it right [here](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-all-transactions-of-an-address) along with [youtube video](https://youtu.be/kpxgYuC4uyA) if that is what you preferred.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several services that allow you to query all transactions related to a specific smart contract. Etherscan, for example, provides a "View Contract" feature that allows you to view the contract's code, its transaction history, and its internal transactions. Additionally, you can use the web3.js library to interact with the Ethereum blockchain and retrieve information about a specific contract, including its transaction history. Other blockchain explorers such as blockscout, ethplorer, and enjinx also allow you to view transaction history related to a specific smart contract.