# Is there an api to get list of transactions from non forked blockchain / classic Ethereum

Tags: transactions, ethereum-classic

Now that the hard fork is complete, there are two blockchains - the forked one for ETH (at 1920000) and the original is for the ETC.

The etherscan.io provide an api to get list of transactions for ETH but I do not think that they will support the non forked blockchain (ETC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify (remove tx if in for loop) the [following](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth) function to get all transactions between a starting and an end block:

```
function getTransactionsByAccounts(myaccount, startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
  if (endBlockNumber == null) {
    endBlockNumber = eth.blockNumber;
    console.log("Using endBlockNumber: " + endBlockNumber);
  }
  if (startBlockNumber == null) {
    startBlockNumber = endBlockNumber - 1000;
    console.log("Using startBlockNumber: " + startBlockNumber);
  }
  console.log("Searching for transactions to/from account \"" + myaccount + "\" within blocks "  + startBlockNumber + " and " + endBlockNumber + "\"");

  for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
      console.log("Searching block " + i);
    }
    var block = eth.getBlock(i, true);
    if (block != null && block.transactions != null) {
      block.transactions.forEach( function(e) {
        if (myaccount == "*" || myaccount == e.from || myaccount == e.to) {
          console.log("  tx hash          : " + e.hash + "\n"
            + "   nonce           : " + e.nonce + "\n"
            + "   blockHash       : " + e.blockHash + "\n"
            + "   blockNumber     : " + e.blockNumber + "\n"
            + "   transactionIndex: " + e.transactionIndex + "\n"
            + "   from            : " + e.from + "\n" 
            + "   to              : " + e.to + "\n"
            + "   value           : " + e.value + "\n"
            + "   gasPrice        : " + e.gasPrice + "\n"
            + "   gas             : " + e.gas + "\n"
            + "   input           : " + e.input);
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

and use a recent version of **geth** (i.e. 1.4.1) with the following flag set:

```
--oppose-dao-fork   # Updates the chain rules to oppose the DAO hard-fork
```

Comment: You mentioned "remove tx if in for loop". Do you mean "skip the transaction if the transaction hash was found in previous iteration of the for loop"?

Comment: Yes, remove the "if" statement and it will output all transactions.

Answer (score 1):

try https://etcchain.com/api

include ethereum classic block, transaction, price，miner index，Hope you like it.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer but I already accepted another answer. However I upvoted it.

Comment: Two years later... thanks. Does it have testnet/morden version? also ssl access certificate is complaining.