# How to detect the balance change in solidity

Tags: solidity, evm

In contract, there are always some storage change like token transfer.
I want to detect the token transfer event.
Token always store in contract mapping struct. So how can i detect the mapping change or the variables change in contract storage and recognize this is a token change event?

Answer (score 1):

You want to detect this from outside the contract, right? For example in an application using web3.js?

In the contract, create an event with the information you want and call it when the token transfer happens.

See here for how you can then listen for that event:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events

Comment: Actually, i want parse all those token transfer in blockchain. And the method i think is parse from the event logs. If there is no event be set while coding, maybe parse this kind of balance change can be really hard

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
function checkAllBalances() { 
  var i =0; 
  eth.accounts.forEach( function(e){
    console.log("  eth.accounts["+i+"]: " +  e + " \tbalance: " + web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(e), "ether") + " ether"); 
    i++; 
  })
};
```

taken from [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth) thread.

**Edit:**

From inside the contract you can't. The only block variables you have access to are mentioned [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html).

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  I want parse all the token balance in contract. I found it can be obtain in etherscan.io, so i am confused how to get it.

Comment: etherscan.io is used for the main net meaning that balances have an equivalent in real currency. Have a look at their API: https://etherscan.io/apis

Comment: Yes, i know that. I want do the same api with etherscan.io. And got some problem.