# how can we get ledger way of Debits/Credits happened on blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, transactions

i am using geth and want to have a list of all the transactions (debits/credits) happened on my privatenet. like the way ledger is being used.
is there any way to do this?  and how to get all the transactions of a given address? any other way other than using a contract? could you please help me to solve this.

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3478/1268