# How to use miner.start(2) from javascript

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, dapp-development, javascript

Refering to "[Common useful JavaScript snippets for geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth/8006#8006)"

Got Following example to run miner from javascript:

> 1. Mine only when there are transactions!

```
var mining_threads = 1

function checkWork() {
    if (eth.getBlock("pending").transactions.length > 0) {
        if (eth.mining) return;
        console.log("== Pending transactions! Mining...");
        miner.start(mining_threads);
    } else {
        miner.stop(0);  // This param means nothing
        console.log("== No transactions! Mining stopped.");
    }
}

eth.filter("latest", function(err, block) { checkWork(); });
eth.filter("pending", function(err, block) { checkWork(); });

checkWork();
```

I am not able to use `miner.start(mining_threads)`. Currently, I am using the following libraries:

- jquery-1.12.0.min.js
- bignumber.min.js
- web3-light.js
- web3Init.js

It would be really great if someone could help me out here.

Comment: If you're using this by uploading the script through the JavaScript console (`loadScript`) in Geth, it should work.

Comment: Attaching error info will help to resolve.

Comment: did you figure out how to use miner.start() in js file? I got same problem. When it is running and I clicked the function of miner.start(), that warns I dont have a module for miner.start().

Answer (score 5):

miner.start will tell geth to start mining.

For that to work, **you need to load the mining module into geth** when you start geth.  The mining module is not loaded by default.  I'm assuming that is the problem since you didn't post any error info.

See the [official wiki documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining).

Comment: Thanks Ross, you are correct, I loaded the mining module by adding js flag while starting geth, Now I am able to use miner inside js file.