# RPC API query does not retrieve transaction data

Tags: transactions, json-rpc

I am trying to retrieve blockchain transaction data on my node using JSON RPC API, but I get no result.

For example this request :

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByBlockNumberAndIndex","params":["0x29c", "0x0"],"id":1}'
```

Give me this result :

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":null}
```

What am I missing to get something like ? :

```
"id":1,
"jsonrpc":"2.0",
"result": {
    "hash":"0xc6ef2fc5426d6ad6fd9e2a26abeab0aa2411b7ab17f30a99d3cb96aed1d1055b",
    "nonce":"0x",
    "blockHash": "0xbeab0aa2411b7ab17f30a99d3cb9c6ef2fc5426d6ad6fd9e2a26a6aed1d1055b",
    "blockNumber": "0x15df", // 5599
    "transactionIndex":  "0x1", // 1
    "from":"0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1",
    "to":"0x85h43d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1",
    "value":"0x7f110" // 520464
    "gas": "0x7f110" // 520464
    "gasPrice":"0x09184e72a000",
    "input":"0x603880600c6000396000f300603880600c6000396000f3603880600c6000396000f360",
  }
```

PS : my node is still syncing (block #1504330 / #2074754)

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use **geth** IPC directly since it's much easier to use. Modify the following [code](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth):

```
function getTransactionsByAccount(myaccount, startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
  if (endBlockNumber == null) {
    endBlockNumber = eth.blockNumber;
    console.log("Using endBlockNumber: " + endBlockNumber);
  }
  if (startBlockNumber == null) {
    startBlockNumber = endBlockNumber - 1000;
    console.log("Using startBlockNumber: " + startBlockNumber);
  }
  console.log("Searching for transactions to/from account \"" + myaccount + "\" within blocks "  + startBlockNumber + " and " + endBlockNumber);

  for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
      console.log("Searching block " + i);
    }
    var block = eth.getBlock(i, true);
    if (block != null && block.transactions != null) {
      block.transactions.forEach( function(e) {
        if (myaccount == "*" || myaccount == e.from || myaccount == e.to) {
          console.log("  tx hash          : " + e.hash + "\n"
            + "   nonce           : " + e.nonce + "\n"
            + "   blockHash       : " + e.blockHash + "\n"
            + "   blockNumber     : " + e.blockNumber + "\n"
            + "   transactionIndex: " + e.transactionIndex + "\n"
            + "   from            : " + e.from + "\n" 
            + "   to              : " + e.to + "\n"
            + "   value           : " + e.value + "\n"
            + "   time            : " + block.timestamp + " " + new Date(block.timestamp * 1000).toGMTString() + "\n"
            + "   gasPrice        : " + e.gasPrice + "\n"
            + "   gas             : " + e.gas + "\n"
            + "   input           : " + e.input);
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

you would get something like:

```
function getTxFromBlock(blockIndex, txIndex) {

    block = eth.getBlock(blockIndex, true);

    return block.transactions[txIndex];

}
```

Obviously you should do some checking over the indexes so that they are in a valid range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact JSON RPC API works well, but I was querying early blocks without tx data :)