# web3.eth.filter({ fromBlock:1, toBlock: "latest" }).get() not working

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, filters

`web3.eth.filter({ fromBlock:1, toBlock: "latest" }).get()` is not working on my geth console. I downgraded my geth from 1.5.9 to 1.3.5 to resolve this but it's still not working.
Strange thing is that it is working on one machine with geth 1.3.5 but not on a cloud VM with same geth version. 
`web3.eth.filter({ fromBlock:1, toBlock: "latest" }).get()` return `[]` while my blockchain has transactions in the blocks.How to resolve this.

Later I found out that this is not working on the Linux OS. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `{},` before `{ fromBlock`. See https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/blob/master/testing/test_20170205_1849/06_checkEvents.sh#L118 for an example.

---

#### Update Responding To Comment

The following filter retrieves the logs from the Golem Network Token (GNT) contract:

```
var gntAddress="0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d";
var filter=web3.eth.filter({fromBlock: 3492700, toBlock: 3492900, address: [gntAddress], topics: []});
filter.get(function(error, log) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(log));
});
filter.stopWatching();
```

With the results (formatted) including:

```
[
  {"address":"0xa74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d","blockHash":"0x04b0e2a5460d67f293253d63fb4884d0d7e4a06c2774a845274b15b5cbdd68cd","blockNumber":3492715,"data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014152deb07b399d48000","logIndex":0,"removed":false,"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x000000000000000000000000b611b7ca579cac70aee370375aaca089a45ff8be","0x0000000000000000000000000f8fa1b75ccb1cd9a0a52594ba8299468400e8b1"],"transactionHash":"0x388430286ce1d3cba8c40f50cca5dc5d1292e332a0316a8edeef001d4007d380","transactionIndex":2},
  {"address":"0xa74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d","blockHash":"0x0a8cbd40aa2661f7522a95dbe8e32b0386bc8bd462b7fa3b43028a2a9e24411c","blockNumber":3492765,"data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000dbd2fc137a30000","logIndex":0,"removed":false,"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000000536806df512d6cdde913cf95c9886f65b1d3462","0x000000000000000000000000396a0fa0abd2251a3676d65d2d03fcbb9c3075fd"],"transactionHash":"0x267e85a582504e034e95d879c13c423daf38daca7f3ccf4dfe5ca8b80cbac758","transactionIndex":1},
  {"address":"0xa74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d","blockHash":"0x2262a2564025aa4a4cc10af04846c12db6081ed36e222cec874da936f0e09f6a","blockNumber":3492807,"data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100803c9fee14a4b400","logIndex":1,"removed":false,"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000000536806df512d6cdde913cf95c9886f65b1d3462","0x000000000000000000000000396a0fa0abd2251a3676d65d2d03fcbb9c3075fd"],"transactionHash":"0x5a2a7884c2503b62dbed94cdab1d019b58034ea5e75cd64fd888a87a328590bb","transactionIndex":11},
  {"address":"0xa74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d","blockHash":"0x32cef6508d6a955f45ba8375fb951ea8371b2394c42d9a3691da84c02d2413b7","blockNumber":3492827,"data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a49105c21659ba0000","logIndex":1,"removed":false,"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x000000000000000000000000d94c9ff168dc6aebf9b6cc86deff54f3fb0afc33","0x0000000000000000000000008741ee12d356e284512ef4ecaf7e94b6d3ae613d"],"transactionHash":"0xdcaf377c1722c26b5ad508b179fb97d139c6cfb420bb5d9af177af420013083b","transactionIndex":19},
  {"address":"0xa74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d","blockHash":"0xde7849ab8a8ca60f7a9f6783d14f2e9878fa151d4d38695fbddfef959447b106","blockNumber":3492838,"data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a49105c21659ba0000","logIndex":0,"removed":false,"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000008741ee12d356e284512ef4ecaf7e94b6d3ae613d","0x0000000000000000000000000536806df512d6cdde913cf95c9886f65b1d3462"],"transactionHash":"0x5773342d096e55be3b32db817f9b5d4f4cda9268f99daf8e53a05c9742813a10","transactionIndex":7},
  {"address":"0xa74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d","blockHash":"0x6a402d755faab1f5b33955bb5813a66f42f8a14b4f76176f000a1438c34992cb","blockNumber":3492851,"data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001ba077b5641a7280000","logIndex":71,"removed":false,"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x000000000000000000000000b681b19bb1f7e9f3c2ae0edeab368c2afaa4e590","0x0000000000000000000000007d3c699eede108b815f56c49f0f38ff96faf8f3a"],"transactionHash":"0xa2e83637c59baaf52c8f8cafaca3ed1c34264de9a77c13db99a30c40eadfb182","transactionIndex":84},
  {"address":"0xa74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d","blockHash":"0xddf3729cee73969b973128ba4a9fc4b7ba5afc68af21357bb15e201d16777647","blockNumber":3492862,"data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001ba077b5641a7280000","logIndex":2,"removed":false,"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000007d3c699eede108b815f56c49f0f38ff96faf8f3a","0x0000000000000000000000000536806df512d6cdde913cf95c9886f65b1d3462"],"transactionHash":"0xf35e6608a40caa0e1978e76bedf38291fe22718db4cebdabeae883309171c7ad","transactionIndex":10}
]
```

Comment: I tried , it is still not working

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: will it work for general account address not on contract one?

Comment: No. It won't work on Externally Owned Accounts. For contract accounts, it will only produce output for events that the contracts specifically log.

See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth for some scripts that will help you find your transactions.

Comment: I found out that eth.filter is not working fine on ubuntu os. @BokkyPooBah those scripts are not i am looking for. I want to get all the transactions of a blockchain