# How to do searching in Ethereum's Ledge? (SQL)

Tags: go-ethereum, database

Recently, I have a question about searching function in blockchain. Blockchain is a distributed database and as a database, there should be some searching functions such as "Select", "Join". I am wondering if I have 10 contracts in my private blockchain, how can I search according to the attribute inside the contracts? Is that the only way to do it, is to have a registration contract.

Thank

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, ethereum blockchain is a distributed database but you cannot do any query you want (for example, getting all the transactions for a given account needs you to process the whole blockchain, see [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3478/8047) for example).

That being said, there are several methods that allow you to get information without using another tool for processing/indexing besides the ethereum node itself. The API is stated in Ethereum [JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) definition, for example:

- [eth_getbalance](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getbalance) will allow you, given the contract address, to query for it's address.
- [eth_call](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call) is used to send a message to a contract and get information stored within it's state.

I recommend you to take a look at Web3.js which a javascript client. There are good examples [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API).