# transaction history

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am trying to get a list of which accounts sent ether to 1 specific account (or wallet contract), and how much they sent. Is there any function in **web3** that can do this. I assume it would look something like:

```
var transactions = web3.eth.getTransactionHistory();
console.log("sender: " + transactions.sender[0]);
console.log("amount: " + transactions.amount[0]);
```

These are just madeup function names that I'm using to explain what I'm basically looking for. Would anyone know how I might be able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this (modified from [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth/3478#3478)):

```
function getSendersToAccount(myaccount, startBlockNumber) {
  let senders = [];
  let values = [];
  if (endBlockNumber == null) {
    console.log("Using endBlockNumber: " + endBlockNumber);
  }
  if (startBlockNumber == null) {
    startBlockNumber = endBlockNumber - 1000;
    console.log("Using startBlockNumber: " + startBlockNumber);
  }
  console.log("Searching for transactions to \"" + myaccount + "\" within blocks "  + startBlockNumber + " and " + endBlockNumber);

  for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
      console.log("Searching block " + i);
    }
    var block = web3.eth.getBlock(i, true);
    if (block != null && block.transactions != null) {
      block.transactions.forEach( function(e) {
        if (myaccount == e.to) {
          senders.push(e.from);
          values.push(e.value);
        }
      })
    }
  }
  return [senders, values];
}
```

### Shorter code

You could remove the block limits (would make it slower since it has to go from a much earlier time), and get something like this:

```
function getSendersToAccount(myaccount, startBlockNumber) {
  let senders = [];
  let values = [];
  let endBlockNumber = web3.eth.blockNumber;

  for (var i = 1; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    let block = web3.eth.getBlock(i, true);
    if (block != null && block.transactions != null) {
      block.transactions.forEach( function(e) {
        if (myaccount == e.to) {
          senders.push(e.from);
          values.push(e.value);
        }
      })
    }
  }
  return [senders, values];
}
```

Comment: How do I know what block number to start at?