# How fetch transaction history for account quickly using Web3j?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, web3j, rinkeby, java

### Intro

We use [Web3j](https://docs.web3j.io/transactions.html) java library to work with Ethereum network. I use [Rinkeby](https://ethstats.net/) test network wit [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) client at the moment. I got familiar with blockchains only a week ago, so terms I use can be incorrect.

### Brief

Almost all required features are clear for me except transactions history. I've stucked at this point. What I have now is two test methods.

### Examples

- First piece looks up through all history by do post filtering, so it requires a lot of time to get result.

  ```
  @Test
  public void testReplayTransactions() throws Exception {
      EthBlock earliestBlockResponse = web3j.ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, false).send();
      EthBlock.Block earliestBlock = earliestBlockResponse.getBlock();
      LOGGER.info("EARLIEST block number: {}", earliestBlock.getNumber());

      EthBlock latestBlockResponse  = web3j.ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, false).send();
      EthBlock.Block latestBlock = latestBlockResponse.getBlock();
      LOGGER.info("LATEST block number: {}", latestBlock.getNumber());

      DefaultBlockParameter startBlock = DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(latestBlock.getNumber().subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1000)));
      DefaultBlockParameter endBlock = DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(latestBlock.getNumber());
      //DefaultBlockParameter startBlock = DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(earliestBlock.getNumber());
      //DefaultBlockParameter endBlock = DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(earliestBlock.getNumber().add(BigInteger.valueOf(100000)));

      Subscription subscription = web3j
          .catchUpToLatestTransactionObservable(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST)
      //.replayTransactionsObservable(startBlock, endBlock)
          .filter(transaction -> {
              return KnownPeers.initialPeer.getAddress().equals(transaction.getFrom())
                  || KnownPeers.initialPeer.getAddress().equals(transaction.getTo());
          })
          .doOnError(throwable -> LOGGER.error("Error occurred", throwable))
          .doOnCompleted(() -> LOGGER.info("Completed"))
          .doOnEach(notification -> LOGGER.info("OnEach"))
          .subscribe(transaction -> {
              LOGGER.info("Transaction {} of block {}. From {} to {}",
                  transaction.getHash(),
                  transaction.getBlockNumber(),
                  transaction.getFrom(),
                  transaction.getTo());
          });

      Thread.sleep(10000);
      subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  ```
- The next one queries for logs, but nothing returned in the first few seconds. So I guess either it also looks at all transactions or logs are something other.

  ```
  @Test
  public void getLogs() throws Exception {
      PeerInfo peerInfo = KnownPeers.initialPeer;
      EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(
          DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST,
          DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,
          Arrays.asList(peerInfo.getAddress())
      );

      LOGGER.info("Start fetching logs");
      Subscription subscription = web3j
          .ethLogObservable(filter)
          .doOnError(throwable -> LOGGER.error("Error occurred", throwable))
          .subscribe(log -> {
              LOGGER.info("Transaction {} of block {}. From {} to {}",
                  log.getTransactionHash(),
                  log.getBlockNumber(),
                  log.getAddress(),
                  log.getType());
          });

      Thread.sleep(100000);
      subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  ```

### Found links

- [Script To Find Transactions To/From An Account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth/3478#3478) - JS way, but I need Java
- [Getting transaction history for a particular account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25389/getting-transaction-history-for-a-particular-account) - JS way.
- [Official REST API?](https://etherchain.org/documentation/api/#api-Accounts-GetAccountIdTxOffset) - some REST API. Not sure what is this. It seems to be an official API of main network, but I need Web3j solution. It may act as a workaround, but not desired. Also not clear hot use it with test networks (Rinkeby)

### Question

How fetch all transactions for an account quickly. Maybe not all, but 10-20 at once. Max timeout - less than 1-2 secs. [This resource](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/txs?a=0xa847d17Ac1d4a5ac7e6097d3eeEa4c81CD1edFAB&p=1) can do it.

### Update 1

As I see list account transaction is an [opened issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1897) for web3j with a pretty long history. Also found [related topic](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2398/23069) at stackexchange. 
There is some Etherchain API where they have [GetAccountTransactions](https://etherchain.org/documentation/api/#api-Accounts-GetAccountIdTxOffset) REST method, but haven't grasped yet how it is related to my task. I see `Powered by Parity v1.7.8` in the footer

Comment: Hi @invenit. Did you find any solution to get your transaction history? I'm also stock and need some help on that topic.

Answer (score 4):

There is no workaround besides of the links you´ve posted. It will depend of your CPU power, network and database. I believe they (etherscan team) gets data from the blockchain and stores in an indexed database and uses some analytics tools to display data to users.