# Get the transaction list from an address using Web3j

Tags: transactions, web3j

I'm trying to fetch all transaction list using WEB3J (JAVA).

I know I can get it from Etherscan or Bscscan, but the request is limited to the free plan, (which is just 5 calls per second)

I need to call it directly using an RPC request.

Comment: All transactions for a single address?

Comment: yes, for a single address. I'm developing an Crypto Wallet and I need this to check if there are new transaction hash when the user opens the token profile, so it will be called for one single address.

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31176/how-fetch-transaction-history-for-account-quickly-using-web3j