# Is there a tool to list all the internal transactions in a block?

Tags: internal-transactions, tools

I don't think this is possible with the standard JSON-RPC API, but I'd like to get a list of all the internal transactions in a block. By internal transactions I mean transactions initiated by a contract, sending to another address. Like what is listed on [EtherScan in the "Internal" tab](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa4883999ba184d7feec0bffa1fa994993c8af4caf602cb6182b1ed7892f82115#internal), but instead of searching by address, search by block.

Are there any tools for this? If not with a standard node out of the box, or maybe there is a third party services for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common useful JavaScript snippets for geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth)

Comment: Looking for internal transactions, not regular transactions. Like https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa4883999ba184d7feec0bffa1fa994993c8af4caf602cb6182b1ed7892f82115#internal is one example, but EtherScan only allows querying for internal transactions by address not by block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with both Parity and Geth using a normal node (with some additional configuration params).

Parity has the [trace](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-trace-module) JSON RPC module, and Geth has its [debug](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug) module.

Parity offers `trace_transaction` whilst Geth offers `traceTransaction`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
function checkTransactionCount(startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
    console.log("Searching for non-zero transaction counts between blocks "  + startBlockNumber + " and " + endBlockNumber);
    for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
        var block = eth.getBlock(i);
        if (block != null) {
            if (block.transactions != null && block.transactions.length != 0) {
                console.log("Block #" + i + " has " + block.transactions.length + " transactions")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[More here](https://lightrains.com/blogs/useful-ethereum-geth-javascript-snippets)

Comment: That looks like regular transactions, not internal transactions... or am I missing something?

Comment: @SteveEllis yes you are right, looks like I missed it. I will keep it here anyway, if anybody want to downvote :D