# Find deployed contract address if you loose it

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-invocation

How do we find the address of a contract, if we loose the address that we deployed at?

Comment: Do you know the address that created it? Then you could check the transaction it made (contract creation) on etherscan.io or any other block explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know which account was used to generate the contract then you can get the transactions done by that account, use this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3478/16048)

Among alternatives, You have following options:

- If you know which network you deployed on, you can check your transactions in etherscan of that corresponding network.
- If you know the which account nonce was used to deploy the transaction, you can use the same account nonce to deploy another contract on any other network, and it will generate same address.