# web3 detect/listen to events if someone send ether to addresses

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript

I need to constantly keep running some code to detect if someone has in the past minute sent some ether/token to a lot of addresses, is there better way to do than https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3478/39163 that gets all transcations to one address and then somehow compare the current time with transaction time to determine if its just happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than pull data every minute, we can use a subscription to get push requests to monitor an address. You can do this using Web3.js 1.0 through `web3.eth.subscribe`: [subscribe("logs")](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-logs)

```
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws');

var subscription1 = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x06012c8cf97BEaD5deAe237070F9587f8E7A266d'
}, function (error, result) {
})
.on("data", function (log) {
    //console.log(log);
    web3.eth.getTransaction(log.transactionHash)
        .then(function (transaction) {
            //console.log(transaction)
            if (transaction.value > 0) {
                console.log("Ether sent from " + transaction.from + " to " + transaction.to)
            }
        })
})
```

This subscription should be listening to the blockchain for any transactions to an address which has a value > 0. These should appear nearly real time.

> Ether sent from 0xcdF5EAD1c329584d835C2Bf6f828C5cAb9B611E6 to 0xb1690C08E213a35Ed9bAb7B318DE14420FB57d8C
>
> Ether sent from 0x9c539429C2caD0c58aeCe00C13B5B7A5977217fb to 0xb1690C08E213a35Ed9bAb7B318DE14420FB57d8C
>
> Ether sent from 0xcdF5EAD1c329584d835C2Bf6f828C5cAb9B611E6 to 0xb1690C08E213a35Ed9bAb7B318DE14420FB57d8C
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no fool-proof way to do this, the best you can do is to run a full node and keep checking `unconfirmed balances` of the required addresses. Few caveats are;

1. Node sync delay
2. 3rd party client `txn` submit delay.