# Get lastest input transaction of the account

Tags: web3js, transactions, javascript

I am trying to get the recent **IN** transaction of the account
while i try

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount("0xF092966e7bcc2b5646e0F0c20A715584DB37cd4B").then(function(trans){
    console.log(trans);
});
```

This returns account transactions count.

I refer web3 documentation and refer net i found the script **getTransactionsByAccount** **[Common useful JavaScript snippets for geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth/3478#3478)**

Is any another way to find `IN` transaction  of the account using web3.js . Lastest last `IN transaction` is enough .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier and faster to use [Amberdata.io](https://amberdata.io/dashboards/applications). If you [get a free api key](https://amberdata.io/pricing) then you can do the following to get the latest `IN` transaction.

It would look something like this:

```
curl \
  -X GET \
  -H "x-api-key: UAK000000000000000000000000demo0001" \
"https://web3api.io/api/v1/addresses/0xF092966e7bcc2b5646e0F0c20A715584DB37cd4B/transactions?to=0xF092966e7bcc2b5646e0F0c20A715584DB37cd4B&size=1"
```

The transactions are returned ordered by timestep. 
The `to` filters by a `to` address. In this case we want all transactions where the `to` address is the address we are querying and we want the first one so I put `size=1`. Although if you remove that you'll get **every** `IN` transaction.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you @foba . is amberdata api free of use ?

Comment: is any API for getting blocks between timestamp/date ?

Comment: Yup it is free to use! It's free and easy to get an api key.

Comment: i am not able to find the limit of amberdata API . what is the limit for this API perday/perminute/persecond ?

Comment: As far I know there's currently no rate limit. Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes it is working