# How can i get confirmed transactions from an address?

Tags: python

I'm looking for some way to listen to transactions happening on [this address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d). Basically, whenever a new transaction is confirmed, i would like to receive it. How can i do that? I just got started to web3 and Infura so i don't really know where to go from here.

I tried the Infura websocket, with very little results:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def connect():
    uri = "wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/<MY-PROJECT>"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as ws:
        await ws.send('{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["logs", {"address": "0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d"}]}')

        while True:
            msg = await ws.recv()
            message = json.loads(msg)
            print(message)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connect())
```

This should subscribe to all the events happening on the smart contract, but i'm receiving nothing. Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: There is a question with some useful javascript snippets https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth. It should be an easy exercise to write them in python.