# List all transactions for a block

Tags: blocks, explorer-api

Within a program, I would like to process a list of all normal transactions for an Ethereum block. Specifically for each transaction in the block the transferred ETH value, sender address and receiver address is needed.

Explorers have such lists (e.g. https://etherscan.io/txs?block=12702435), but I cannot find an API which provide this information directly in one API call.

In two steps it is doable:

1. get all txhashes eg. https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/blocks/12702435
2. get sender, receiver and amount for each txhash
   However, this solution is also difficult because of API rate limits

Thank a lot for your help!

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth/2541

Comment: Try one of this scripts: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth/2541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user216: Thanks for your comment.
Indeed, an easy way is to install geth and run a light node with

```
geth --syncmode "light"
```

Then install web3 via pip. Afterwards the following Python code works :)

```
w3 = web3.Web3(web3.Web3.IPCProvider('/home/user/.ethereum/geth.ipc'))
block = w3.eth.get_block(12704257) # example for a recent block
for tx_hash in block['transactions']:
    tx = w3.eth.get_transaction(tx_hash)
    tx_obj = {'addr_sender': tx['from'], 'addr_receiver': tx['to'], 'value': tx['value']}
```