# Get all transactions from blocks in a range of blocknumbers web3

Tags: web3js, blockchain, calldata, chaindata

have seen similar post before, but can seam to get anything working. I am trying to pull block data (mostly all transactions) from a range of blocks (startBlock-endBlock) but keep getting errors or the function checks out but i return "undefined"

Using a function I found here just to grab transaction counts by block range (working up to full list) :[Common useful JavaScript snippets for geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth)

```
function checkTransactionCount(startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
  console.log("Searching for non-zero transaction counts between blocks "  + startBlockNumber + " and " + endBlockNumber);

  for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    var block = web3.eth.getBlock(i);
    if (block != null) {
      if (block.transactions != null && block.transactions.length != 0) {
        console.log("Block #" + i + " has " + block.transactions + " transactions")
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

but get "undefined" when i run `checkTransactionCount(startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber).`

pretty new to web3.js, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`web3.eth.getBlock(i)` is an asynchronous function, you should either use a callback or async / await. Because you are not waiting for the result, you get `undefined` simply because there is no result (yet).

Here is a version using the callback :

```
function checkTransactionCount(startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
  console.log(
    "Searching for non-zero transaction counts between blocks " +
      startBlockNumber +
      " and " +
      endBlockNumber
  );

  for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    web3.eth.getBlock(i, (err, block) => {
      if (err == null && block != null) {
        if (block.transactions != null && block.transactions.length != 0) {
          console.log(
            "\n\nBlock #" + i + " has " + block.transactions + " transactions"
          );
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Or as stated above, you could use async / await like so :

```
async function checkTransactionCount(startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
  console.log(
    "Searching for non-zero transaction counts between blocks " +
      startBlockNumber +
      " and " +
      endBlockNumber
  );

  for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    let block = await web3.eth.getBlock(i);
    if (block != null) {
      if (block.transactions != null && block.transactions.length != 0) {
        console.log(
          "\n\nBlock #" + i + " has " + block.transactions + " transactions"
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT** : Here is an example using async / await returning an array with the transactions hash that are present between `startBlockNumber` and `endBlockNumber` :

```
const Web3 = require("Web3");
const ENDPOINT = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_PROJECT_ID";

let web3 = new Web3(ENDPOINT);

async function checkTransactionCount(startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {
  transactions = [];

  for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    let block = await web3.eth.getBlock(i);
    if (block != null) {
      if (block.transactions != null && block.transactions.length != 0) {
        transactions = transactions.concat(block.transactions);
      }
    }
  }

  return transactions;
}

async function main() {
  console.log(
    "Searching for non-zero transaction counts between blocks 2000000 and 2000010"
  );
  let transactions = await checkTransactionCount(2000000, 2000010);

  console.log(transactions.length + " transactions found");
  console.log(transactions);
}

main();
```

Comment: So, this function seams to work, but I still can’t call it into a dataset/ object, what am I missing here…this is my example [notebook] (https://observablehq.com/d/a9be02e6ce765558), but if I run the function the call `data = await functionName(startblocknumber, endblocknumber)’ I still get undefined

Comment: Well your function is not returning anything, so that's what you'd have to change, do you need an example of that ? I just made the function you provided work, now if you want it to return the set of transactions just tell me and I can add the appropriate versions.

Comment: Yah, That would be super helpful. I’m using 1.6 with infuria. Thanks for helping a newb, will have to work on my Java script!

Comment: even with the edit i still end up with undefined when i call main() or data = main().then(console.log)

Comment: You definitely need to learn more JavaScript, the edit makes the function `checkTransactionCount` return an array of transactions, it should be called like in my example : ` let transactions = await checkTransactionCount(2000000, 2000010);` where you can change the start and end block of course.

Comment: Yah, learning JS is defiantly a priority. Thanks for the help! the call worked as you suggested. I guess i don't understand the point of the main() function above. here is that call i used in the end `blocksdata = {
  console.log(
    "Searching for non-zero transaction counts between blocks 2000000 and 2000010"
  );
  let transactions = await checkTransactionCount(startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber);
   console.log(transactions.length + " transactions found");
   console.log(transactions);
   return transactions;
 }
`

Comment: This was just to get a top level async function to show how to use the `checkTransactionCount` function, but don't bother with that, it was just for the example.