# Tracking contracts and transactions associated with an account address

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, mist

The base set up is a geth based private test-net and a mist wallet is interfacing the node on a local host machine. A few contracts have been deployed through the wallet from 2 different accounts on the same node. I am trying to build a tracker that tracks contracts deployed and associated with contracts of which an account has transacted with in either-direction (from/to). The objective is to build a webpage with the following tabulated lists:
a. List of accounts and the corresponding contract tokens deployed from the accounts on the node. This can be obtained since the node has the contract ABI and the contract address and accordingly, the contract details (attributes).
b. List of contracts associated with an account - contract tokens that are incoming/outgoing from the account on the node
Questions:
 1. Within Mist, upon interacting with the contract which has a transfer of tokens native to the contract to another account on the node, I am able to get the remaining tokens balance. At this point, at either of the account views, Mist is able to retrieve the contract name and address at the second account's view. How to track contracts and retrieve address and ABI of the contract in case above second account was at a different node, using API?
 2. With ref to list b, above, how to get the list of all contracts - ABI and addresses and associated accounts?
 3. The contract has event filters to track for transactions, some of which transactions have been made several days ago from either of the accounts on the node. These exist on the Mist wallet - is it possible to retrieve past transactions using the API? Is there a way to filter the blocks which contain transactions and those associated with contract tokens?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/how-to-list-transactions-from-account-address and http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions