# How to get history transactions towards a batch of given smart contracts in ethereum mainnet and replay these transaction again in private chains?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain

I have a batch of ethereum mainnet smart contracts (about 4,000). Now I want to do some researches:

1. Get all history transactions that are sent to these contracts in ethereum mainnet;
2. Replay these transactions in my private chain.

So, how to implement these in a relatively fast and convenient way?

Comment: Several questions and answers are related to this problem such as [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/how-to-list-transactions-from-account-address), but it can not be used in a batch of target smart contracts.